# React: make typescript infer children type based on conditions in another component

Tags: reactjs, typescript, jsx

I want to write a component that render its children only if some given prop is not null (e.g. to render a loader while fetching some data and update with the actual data when fetch completes).
This is pretty simple:

```
import React, { ReactElement, ReactNode, useState } from 'react'

type TState = {
    data: {
        text: string
    } | null
}

type NotNullProps = {
    children: ReactNode
    state: TState
}

const NotNull = ({ children, state }: NotNullProps) => {
    if (!state.data) {
      return null
    }

    return <>{children}</>
}
```

Now, what if I want to use this component **this way**?

```
const Example = () => {
    const [state] = useState<TState>({ data: null })

    return (
        <NotNull state={state}>
            <div>{state.data.text}</div> // <--- "Object is possibly 'null'."
        </NotNull>
    )
}
```

Typescript correctly signals that `state.data` can be null because it can't infer what is happening in `NotNull`, but `state.data` will never be null since `NotNull` checks for it.
I know this can be solved with render props but they add a bit of clutter to the code. So, is there a way to type `NotNull` in such a way that typescript does not complains/can infer what is happening?

Here's a playground to try it: https://tsplay.dev/zwORWq

(Yes, I know about `Suspense` and other stuff but it is not relevant to this question. I just want to know if there's a way to type this component in a way that typescript can infer that the value is not null (again, without render props)).

Answer (score 1):

You will still have to check for whether `state.data` is `null` because even though your `NotNull` component prevents the children from being *rendered*, your code will still result in a `TypeError` with your usage if `state.data` is `null`, because the line `state.data.text` in your code will produce `TypeError: Cannot read property 'text' of null` when it is interpreted, whether or not the children render. I would suggest just changing the lines to:

```
return (
    <NotNull state={state}>
        <div>{state.data && state.data.text}</div>
    </NotNull>
)
```

But of course, this would negate the need for the `NotNull` component in the first place, except that it also prevents the `<div>` in your example from being rendered

Comment: Yes, this is *one of* the possible solutions, but is not what has been asked in the question

Comment: Unless you restructure this code somehow, it is impossible to prevent an error from occurring in erroneous code. If you want you can use the not-null `!` assertion symbol which signals to TypeScript that you are sure the data is not `null`. But again, in cases where it _is_ `null` (because again, preventing it from rendering does nothing to prevent the possible `null` property access in your code), your code is guaranteed to error out